# Value is undefined while passing data with Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to pass data with Context API to child components. Value is getting `undefined` upon fetching it from a component.

**Component Hierarchy**:

- passing data to a component `MockTable` and `UsecasePane`
- `MainContent -> MockTable`
- `MainContent -> AddMock -> TabContent -> UsecasePane`

=> *MockContext.js*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const MockContext = createContext();

// provider
export const MockProvider = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
   // data fetch and setting the state

  return (
    <MockContext.Provider data={[data, setData]}>
      {props.children}
    </MockContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

- Note: I'm getting response from the API.

Now in `MainContent`, components are encapsulated as follows:

```
// MainContent.js

import React from "react";
import { MockProvider } from "../MockContext";

const MainContent = () => {
  return (
    <MockProvider>
      <div>
        <CustomerTable />
        <AddMock />
        <MockTable />
      </div>
    </MockProvider>
  );
};
```

When I try to fetch the data in `MockTable` or in `UseCasePane`, value is `undefined`.

```
// MockTable.js

import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { MockContext } from "./MockContext";

const MockTable = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useContext(MockContext);
  console.log(data);

  // rest of the code

}
```

Please correct me where I'm going wrong :)

I tried to pass a String  as well from the context and fetched in a component like:

```
return (
    <MockContext.Provider data={"Hello"}>
      {props.children}
    </MockContext.Provider>
  );
```

```
// in MockTable.js
const value = useContext(MockContext); ==> undefined
```

Comment: There was no error right?

Comment: What is undefined? You're logging data1 instead of data?

Comment: @AyushWalia: There is error. It will shows object is not iterable since the value is undefined

Comment: @codemax: sorry! typo. Please check again :)

Comment: Is response.data an array and was it set correctly in the <MockProvider />?

Comment: @codemax yes it is an array. Also I tried passing a string as well to troubleshoot then also value is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct prop to pass into the `Provider` is `value`, **not** `data`. (See: [`Context.Provider`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider))

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const MockContext = createContext();

// provider
export const MockProvider = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios
      .get(config.App_URL.getAllRoute, {
        params: {
          customHostName: config.host,
          type: config.type,
        },
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Error in fetching the data ${error}`);
      });
    console.log(response.data);
    setData(response.data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <MockContext.Provider value={[data, setData]}>
      {props.children}
    </MockContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: I suggest cleaning up the code block to only the line(s) that matters. The answer currently contains a lot of noise since you copied the whole code block but only changed one thing. I would show only the `<MockContext.Provider value={...}>` line, or the whole return statement. Everything above the return statement only makes the answer less readable imo.

Comment: Thanks @codeMax :) and 3limin4t0r for your suggestions. i'll clean up the code block